# Validar números telefónicos de latinoamerica

Tags: php, asterisk

me gustaría saber si existe alguna API o con que herramienta puedo validar que existan los números de teléfono que se ingresan en un formulario, he usado quienhabla.mx pero esa solo me permite validar números de México

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para México puedes usar el [Plan Nacional de Numeración](https://sns.ift.org.mx:8081/sns-frontend/planes-numeracion/descarga-publica.xhtml) del IFT. Es un CSV y lo puedes usar para identificar el NIR, la serie y que el número se encuentre dentro del rango. Si quieres hacer esto de manera automática, ya tienes la información, sólo te faltaría integrar la lógica.

Comment: estuve investigando un poco y vi que el NIR es la lada pero todavía no se cual es el numero de serie y los rangos, el número como esta compuesto?, NIR=998, 1234567, los 7 últimos dígitos que representan?

Comment: Los siguientes tres son la serie y los últimos 4 son los consecutivos. En la lista viene como el más bajo y el más alto, por ejemplo 442 323 1000 al 442 323 3999, cualquiera que esté en ese rango existe, no quiere decir que esté activo o asignado, pero existe.

Answer (score 0):

Si es una validación desde una pagina web (formulario web), puedes usar la liberaría `libphonenumber` que puede revisar en este [enlace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js). Yo la uso y me funciona bien. También existe en PHP dicha librería. Saludos